# Problems with Hiren's boot USB flash drive creation from a downloaded ISO

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I was trying to make Hiren's boot USB flash drive (I opted for NTFS) but Rufus said:

> Unsupported file system, only FAT/Fat32 is supported for this **type of ISO**. Please select FAT/FAT32 as the File system.

In BIOS, USB flash drive with Fat32 file system is not seen/recognized by the PC, so it is not possible to boot with Hiren's boot USB flash drive.

Does anyone know anything about .ISO files? Is it possible to create .ISO from extracted Hiren's files in such a fashion that Rufus allows me to create Hiren's boot USB flash drive with NTFS option?

Comment: What kind of firmware do you have? UEFI type or the old PC BIOS? (Motherboard model?) It's extremely unusual for both kinds to refuse to boot from FAT32 however...

Comment: You don't need to use Rufus. Ventoy is a lot more flexible and easier to use. Just install it to the target USB stick then simply copy as many ISOs you want/need and fit, obviously, to the root.

Comment: Are you sure the machine cannot boot from FAT32?? Has the USB been formatted **exFAT**, instead, which is proprietary and usually not bootable? What PC is being used?

Comment: If Rufus is indicating that the Hiren's boot ISO does not support NTFS, then that is absolutely the case, which means you are at a standstill if your system truly does not support either FAT32. The incompatability comes from the ISO your attempting to use not Rufus.

Comment: Although my answer would have worked, you solved this a different way.  You should post that as an answer instead of "Follow Up", wait a day, accept your own answer.

Comment: Long before I've found this site I have seen Hiren's Boot CD PE. The sentence: "Requires Windows 7 and later." stood out like a sore thumb. 

Despite that, idiotic as it may seem, I have even tried it (beggars can't be choosers and one never knows) but no go for WinXP.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer.
Don't use Rufus and use what is suggested on the [page](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/usb-booting/).  Let that tool do whatever it will.  I think the result was NTFS but I am too lazy to dig out one of my USB sticks to check.

Rufus is a great tool but I have had issues with it here and there creating Windows Installation media and Hirens boot.

The exe to use can be found [here](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/files/ISO2USB.exe) or use the link found on Hiren's page.